# C++ issue with function templates(no instance found)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
    template<typename T, int P>
    T matematika(T polje[], int N) {
      //CODE...
    }
```

this is where the error is(no instance of function template "matematika" matches the specified type)

```
template<>
string matematika(string polje[], int N) {     // ERROR
  //CODE...
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to do template specialization or something else?

Comment: Your `int P` looks like a mistake, and that mistake is causing your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The normal syntax for specialising templates requires you to provide the specialisation's template arguments following the name in the specialisation declaration. Example:

```
template <class T>
struct Container {};

template <>
struct Container<int> {};
```

When specialising a function template (and only a function template), you can omit the arguments if they are deducible from the specialisation. That would be the case e.g. here:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T t) {}

// One valid way to specialise:
template <>
void foo<int>(int i) {}

// Another valid way to specialise:
template <>
void foo(int i) {}
```

However, this only applies if the template arguments can be deduced from the specialisation. In your situation, that's not the case, since there's nothing to deduce `P` from. You must therefore provide the value explicitly:

```
template<>
string matematika<string, /*Whatever value of P you want to specialise for*/>(string polje[], int N) {
  //CODE...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you would like to pass an array with known size at compile time and than overload the function for strings?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, int N>
T matematika(T (&polje)[N]) 
{
  cout << "array version: " << polje << endl;
  return polje[0];
}

std::string::value_type matematika(std::string const& polje)
{
  cout << "string version: " << polje << endl;
  return polje[0];
}


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    cout << "got: " << matematika("test") << endl;
    cout << "got: " << matematika(string("string")) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you used `int P` as second template parameter you'll still have to keep it:

```
template<typename T, int P>
T matematika(T polje[], int N) { // (1)
    ...
}
template<int P> // T = string
string matematika(string polje[], int N) { // (2)
    ...
}
```

Then you could use these:

```
int matematika<int, 111>(int*, int); // (1)
string matematika<22>(string*, int); // (2)
```

Note that, (2) is new template function, unrelated to (1).

If you want to have specialization of (1):

```
template<>  // T = string, int P = 10
string matematika<string, 10>(string polje[], int N) { // (3)
    ...
}
```

Then you could use this one:

```
string matematika<string, 10>(string*, int); // (3)
string matematika<string, 11>(string*, int); // (1)
```

However, it's not clear at all from your question why you need `int P` in your original template. Perhaps that meant to be used as an array size. Something like this:

```
templattemplate<typename T, int P>
T matematika(T (&polje)[P])
```

Comment: This `string matematika<22>(string*, int); // (2)` isn't a specialization.  Which means someone could do `string matematike<string, 22>` and the OP would be very surprised.

Comment: @Yakk I thought it was clear that <A, B> will call (1), and <A> will call (2). Basic template rules, no surprises there. (2) isn't related to (1), it just has the same function name as (1)

Comment: Sure; I'm just noting that the surprise case is very important.